# How to serve user-uploaded files (or file trees) with Spring Boot and Tomcat?

Tags: spring, tomcat, file-upload, spring-boot, static-files

What is the **best way to serve public static files uploaded at run-time** by users using Spring (Boot) and (embedded) tomcat?

Moreover, is there an elegant way to upload and serve static file trees directly?

We are building a CMS that enables internal users like designers or front-end developers to directly upload their work on our server. It often consists in several files linked together by a relative path, so it could be really easier to have something to handle file trees directly. Files are always static as dynamic features only run on client-side.
It could be helpful to purpose implementation ideas if there is no standard solution available (like using a zip then recreating its internal organisation into tomcat public folder).

Comment: Little info : [Spring Boot Upload](http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) ; [Spring Multi-File Upload](http://www.ama-dev.com/hello-world/) ; [Serving Static Files with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)

Comment: General hint: treat your application as read-only. You want to be able to delete it and redeploy it. Corollary: treat the uploaded files as data, entered by the user. So store them outside of your application, and implement a Spring controller to serve them.

Comment: Thanks, I agree I need to store them outside of my application. But the data is used as it is when uploaded, so why should I have to write a controller to give it back? Additionally, this controller will do the same work as any web server : checking the url, finding the resource then returning it through http. And then the performance matters, so I'll have to write more code to make it cacheable, etc. I find the development overhead huge compared to the commonness of this feature, isn't there any other solution?

Comment: You could write them to a directory that is served directly by a web server, but I assume that you won't let any random visitor access the files of any user. That, alone is sufficient to desire a controller that controls access to the uploaded files. Frankly, reading bytes from a file and writing them to a stream is far from being a huge task.

Comment: Those files are always public because all authorization is done at the API level, when required by the code those files embed. So yes it is a solution to copy files to a web server directory. If you find how to do it with an embedded tomcat using spring boot, I'll validate your answer right away. And if it works for file trees too, I'm going to bless you ;)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "all authorization is done at the API level". If you make a JPEG file (for example) publicly available through a web server serving static files, then anyone will be able do access it.

Comment: Regarding file trees, if your goal is to let users download multiple files at once, you don't have much choice other than generating a zip file and let them download the zip file. If that must be done dynamically, you'll also need a controller to do it.

Comment: It means that if a JPEG file is to be protected, it'll be stored in a DB, accessed through a secured spring controller and fetched from an ajax request containing the security token.
I agree I have not much choice regarding multiple files upload, but I still have hope someone knows a standard solution :)